# Asp.Net Core And Active Directory

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, active-directory

I need source code or tutorial for write program with Asp.net Core
for Active Directory such as :
1- Create a user account 
2- Add a user to a group
3- Disable a user account
4- Search user's
5- Set user's password
Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: It will be easier to suggest a way forward for you if you say what it is that you're trying to achieve.  Do you just want to set-up an AD user account, or do you want an application capable of setting up such an an account?

Comment: I want write an applicetion for active directory with asp.net

Comment: What would that application need to do?  Create users, delete users, list users?

Comment: Set user's password - 
- Add a user to a group           
- Create a user account         
- Disable a user account
- Search user's

Comment: It looks like there's a few tutorials around: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C was the first hit on Google

Comment: thankyou for your guide